# Redirect without changing url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirection

I want to create a file .htaccess for a invisible redirection.
The goal is when i input www.**site1**.com i have to redirect to www.**site2**.com without changing url in address bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/q/214512

Answer (score 0):

No can do, you could [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) the requests though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if both sites are on the same Apache instance. If they're on different servers (or if site2 is run by different software) then you'll need to do the reverse proxy that MindTheMonkey is talking about.